# How do I left join onto a mysql range case group by query?

Tags: mysql

How do I LEFT JOIN an average onto this query?

```
select t.range, count(*) as num
from
   (select case
       when price < 50000 then '0 - 49K'
       when price >= 50000 and price < 100000 then '50 - 99K'
       when price >= 100000 and price < 200000 then '100 - 199K'
       ...
       as range,
       price
       from table) as t
group by range
```

I've tried

```
select t.range, count(*) as num, avg(b.val)
from
   (select case
       when price < 50000 then '0 - 49K'
       when price >= 50000 and price < 100000 then '50 - 99K'
       when price >= 100000 and price < 200000 then '100 - 199K'
       ...
       as range,
       price
       from table) as t
    left join table2 b on b.id = t.id
group by range
```

And various other feeble attempts to no avail.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (it's late here) but I don't see id field in t definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly without knowing more about what "table2" is and how it relates to "table", but my first thought would be to do the join inside your subquery instead of outside of it:

```
select t.range, count(*) as num, avg(t.val)
from
   (select case
       when price < 50000 then '0 - 49K'
       when price >= 50000 and price < 100000 then '50 - 99K'
       when price >= 100000 and price < 200000 then '100 - 199K'
       ...
       as range,
       t1.price,
       b.val
       from table t1
       left join table2 b on b.id = t1.id
) as t
group by range
```